# How to traverse through three selection related combo boxes with enable disable state

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I spend a lot of time trying to resolve this.
I have 3 combo boxes, i`m trying to make first active when the form is loaded and the rest inactive.
When the value (double type) is selected in first cmb, second is activated and first become inactive, than the value is selected in second and first remain inactive and second become inactive activating the third one after selecting value from the third combo box first become active and the rest inactive until the selection start again.

THIS IS ON WINDOWS FORMS

I tried with loops but quickly become very complicated :-(
I hope this is clear enough :-)

Thank you

Comment: Is this a WinForms app?

Comment: Add your code to your question.

Comment: Yes Windows Forms.

Comment: Kinetic, after many attempts I deleted the code. Thinking to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use events, like SelectionChangeCommitted. Event handlers are used to call methods automatically when certain conditions are met, and so allow you to execute certain conditional actions without polling with a loop. Here's an example that should do what you're looking for, although it would make for a somewhat non-user friendly gui.

```
public partial class ExampleForm : Form
{
    public ExampleForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.Enabled = true;
        comboBox2.Enabled = false;
        comboBox3.Enabled = false;

        comboBox1.Items.Add("option1");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("option2");

        comboBox2.Items.Add("option1");
        comboBox2.Items.Add("option2");

        comboBox3.Items.Add("option1");
        comboBox3.Items.Add("option2");

        comboBox1.OnSelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_OnSelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox2.OnSelectedIndexChanged += comboBox2_OnSelectedIndexChanged;
        comboBox3.OnSelectedIndexChanged += comboBox3_OnSelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    void comboBox1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Enabled = false;
        comboBox2.Enabled = true;
    }

    void comboBox2_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox2.Enabled = false;
        comboBox3.Enabled = true;
    }

    void comboBox3_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Enabled = true;
        comboBox3.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Verified as working. if you directly copy and paste this example as a new class and step through with a debugger to understand what's going on if it isn't clear.

Comment: user2647513, last three lines of the code just after InitializedComponent vs is telling me that the comboBoxes names does not exist in the current context. Weird as the all code above it is ok - is recognizing all my combos. Thanks for help.

Comment: My event handlers for combos are SelectedIndexChanged yours OnSelectedIndexChanged.

Comment: You must add the combo boxes to the form. If you add them with the designer, you must make sure the `Name` properties are `comboBox1`, `comboBox2`, and `comboBox3`.

Comment: @Thomas that's OK, you may specify whichever name you wish, so long as you attach the method to the correct event handler of the correct object.

Comment: I have combos on the form already, now it works - sort of. When I select 1st one, 3rd one is activated and 1st and 2nd deactivated, when i select 3rd the 1st one is activated and 2nd and 3rd deactivated :-). So the 2nd one is always inactive.

Comment: Ok I think I know why does not work in order. My 2nd combo items are populated from the array list. I commented out an array and added sample collection and it works. Any ideas ? I need to populate 2nd one from an array as is based on what was selected in 1st combo.

Comment: That sounds like a subject for another question. Would you mind selecting my answer if it helped you with your original question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an array for the combo boxes and have all 3 of them use the same `SelectedIndexChanged` handler:

```
// List the combo boxes in the order you want them to enable.
ComboBox[] _boxes = { comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3 };

private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = Array.IndexOf(_boxes, (ComboBox)sender);

    // Disable the combo box that just got its value selected.
    _boxes[index].Enabled = false;

    // If it's not the last combo box in the array, enable the next one.
    if(index < _boxes.Length - 1)
        _boxes[index + 1].Enabled = true;
}
```

Then you just have to set up the initial state of the combo boxes so the first one is enabled and the other two aren't.

This is easily scalable too. If you decide to add another combo box to the flow, you just need to add it to the `_boxes` array.

Comment: itsme86, should I put this code in to one of the combo handlers for example in the comboBox 1 ?

Comment: Put the array inside the `Form1` class, not inside a method. The method should be the event handler for all 3 of the combo box's `SelectedIndexChanged` event. They should all use that same event handler.

Comment: Sorry itsme86 but I`m having trouble to implement this in my current code. I have already three event handlers for 3 combos which are used all over the other parts of the code. I can`t use one event handler for all of them. This is bit more advanced for my c# skills :-)